# Performing action after getting value of button

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code? Ive already got it to alert the value of the button by using alert(y) and getting back 2437 but as soon as i put this condition statement in its not even giving me an alert.

Im sure its something simple but im not seeing it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   if( $('body.single-product').length || $('body.single-product').length ){
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("single_add_to_cart_button");
   var y = x[0].value;
   if y == 2437 {
     alert("Yes");
   }else{
     alert("No");
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: please share relevant html code for better understanding

Comment: You need to change it to `if ( y == 2437 ) {...}`

Comment: Thanks kmoser that was it, cant believe i missed that one -_-

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your javascript code right here: `if y == 2437`

Correct it to this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 if( $('body.single-product').length || $('body.single-product').length ){
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("single_add_to_cart_button");
   var y = x[0].value;
   if (y == 2437) {
     alert("Yes");
   }else{
     alert("No");
   }
 }
});
```